# How to get SSH access to headless Raspbian Stretch Lite? Official way seems not to work

Tags: wifi, ssh, raspbian-stretch, headless

I was not able to enable `ssh` by putting the file into the boot folder, and yes it was created without extension from a `Windows 7` machine and gets deleted after boot.

This is what should have happened:

> For headless setup, SSH can be enabled by placing a file named `ssh`, without any extension, onto the boot partition of the SD card from another computer. When the Pi boots, it looks for the `ssh` file. If it is found, SSH is enabled and the file is deleted. The content of the file does not matter; it could contain text, or nothing at all.

([Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/))

I don't want to go for Keyboard & Monitor as I can get the IP assigned to Respberry Pi 3 when I connect with ethernet and can also ping with 0% lost.

After looking for an answer I got to know that the `ssh` is not enabled and that's the reason `putty` returns Connection refused on every attempt.

Now I see there is `cmdline.txt` in the boot folder is it something that runs on every boot? Can I use to enable `ssh`? If yes, how to do it?

Here are all the details, let me know if something else is required.

- My System: Windows 7 Update 1
- Raspberry model: Raspberry Pi 3 B
- Raspberry OS: Raspbian Stretch Lite
- Monitor: No
- Keyboard: No
- Ping Request: responded with no packet loss
- Connection Type: Ethernet
- SSH: not enabled (How to?)

**EDIT**: 
Now i am able to mount the 'rootfs' to my windows 7 machine with Paragon ExtFS for Windows, but don't know how to enable `ssh` yet, any help is appreciated

Moved from [https://superuser.com/questions/1279354/how-to-get-ssh-access-to-headless-raspbian-stretch-lite-official-way-seems-not/1279491#1279491](https://superuser.com/q/1279354/345746) to here

Comment: You can [have a look at this](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ReadMeFirst.md)... it's written from a Mac user's perspective, but will work just as well in Windows

Comment: I never had any problems with the ssh file. One caveat for me was local DNS. I needed to connect via IP, not by name, because the name was not present at the DNS server. See my question about this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100194/ssh-in-local-lan-works-with-ip-but-not-by-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i was able to find an alternate way to enable `ssh`. I will try to summarize it here. I tried **PiBakery** also but it was too heavy with `nodejs` and keeps on crashing in every attempt.

---

#### The problem: `Ext4` format is not readable form windows

So once you burn Raspbian through any img burning tool it creates two partition `Boot` & `rootfs`. The `boot` partition is formatted in FAT and will be only visible to windows whereas the `rootfs` was with `Ext4` and will not be visible at all (*you can confirm it by viewing it in MiniTool partition Partition Wizard*)

---

#### Mission: Editing the configuration from windows to force enable `ssh`

My mission was to force enable `ssh` as it was not working with the official instructions (*putting `ssh` file in the boot partition)*. So I downloaded the [Paragon ExtFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) which enables Windows 7 to browse/edit files in  `Ext4`partition by mounting it as new drive.

Before that i also tried **Ext2Fsd-0.69** but it was not compatible with Windows 7 and the other **ext2explore-2.2.71** is only capable to view files not to edit them. Nothing worked for me

---

#### The hack: Edit `/etc/rc.local` file from windows 7

After googling for almost the whole day i got to know two thing

1. Commands can be executed by editing the file `/etc/rc.local` in the `rootfs` partition
2. Command to start `ssh` is `/etc/init.d/ssh start`

So i edited the `rc.local` file by placing the `/etc/init.d/ssh start` just before the `exit 0` so that it executes on every boot, as follows

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/etc/init.d/ssh start
exit 0
```

And it worked!! I know it's not a neat way but it can be helpful for someone in need. I must thank ***@KamilMaciorowski*** for his kind help & edits.

[image: raspbian with ssh]

Please comment below if you see any issue that may arise because of it.